# "S'il y a/S'il existe" et "S'il n'y a pas/S'il n'existe pas" plus indicatif ou subjonctif ?

Tags: subjonctif, indicatif, conditions

Source : https://stringfixer.com/fr/Inconsistent_equations

> (...) [U]n système d'équations linéaire (...) est dit
> cohérent s'il y a au moins un ensemble de valeurs pour les inconnues
> **qui satisfait** chaque équation du système (...). En revanche, un
> système d'équations linéaires (...) est appelé incohérent s'il n'y a
> pas d'ensemble de valeurs pour les inconnues **qui satisfasse** toutes
> les équations.

Je ne comprends pas pourquoi avec l'affirmation

> S'il y a

on utilise l'indicatif et avec la négation

> S'il n'y a pas

on utilise le subjonctif. Si on remplace les tournures "s'il y a/s'il n'y a pas" avec "s'il existe/s'il n'existe pas" les modes seront-ils les mêmes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lorsqu'on dit « s'il y a au moins un ensemble de valeurs avec la propriété de satisfaire X », ce qui est la même chose que dire  « s'il y a au moins un ensemble de valeurs pour les inconnues qui satisfait », on fait la supposition qu'un ensemble existe et qu'il satisfait X ; on peut donc dire que l'idée est concrétisée.

> ([français facile](https://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-29261.php)) Quand la proposition relative exprime une idée non concrétisée, le subjonctif est fréquemment employé.
>
> Principalement  quand la relative dépend d'une principale négative ou interrogative.
>
> ♦ Elle n'a rencontré personne qui puisse résoudre son problème.
> ♦ Pensez-vous trouver un costume qui soit acceptable?

Voir aussi [BDL](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=5168)

Comment: Pour existe c'est la même chose, non ?

Comment: @Dimitris Oui, bien sûr ; même si on ne dit pas par exemple « il existe un cheveux dans la soupe », mais seulement « il y a un cheveux dans la soupe » (il y a là une question d'usage que je n'ai pas approfondie), c'est dans la soupe que le cheveux existe. I y a  beaucoup moins de différence d'usage en mathématiques : on peut dire sans problème « [il existe/il y a] un élément x dans S tel que x …»